# Load two dropdowns with the same values

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any problem with loading the same set of values in 2 different HTML form dropdowns? My code looks like this:

```
var dr1=document.getElementById("dr1");
var dr2=document.getElementById("dr2");
for (nombre in elements) {
    var opcion=document.createElement('OPTION');
    var cam=elements[nombre];
    opcion.value=nombre;
    opcion.text=cam["nombreCompleto"];
    //Añadimos a los 2 dropdowns
    dr2.add(opcion, null);
    dr1.add(opcion, null);
    }
dr1.selectedIndex=0;
dr2.selectedIndex=0;
```

This load the same set of values to two different dropdowns. However, when executed, it only loads whatever dropdown appears last in the code; in the above example, it would have been "dr1" (and if I put the "dr2.add(option.null)" line last, it loads that one). If I load only one dropdown (commenting out the other one) it works fine.

All of this is on Firefox 3.6.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your OPTION objects will first be added to dr2, then to dr1. There won't be created copies when calling add, but the object you just created will be moved from *nowhere* to *dr2*, then to *dr1*.

The general idea is that you can't have a DOM object in two different places at the same time. You may want to take a look into JavaScript object cloning. See here for some useful information: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) .

If you just need to clone DOM element objects you can use `cloneNode()`. See here for a complete list of available members and methods: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work.  Refactor the code to create the option node into a function.

```
function createOption(...) {
    var opcion=document.createElement('OPTION');
    var cam=elements[nombre];
    opcion.value=nombre;
    opcion.text=cam["nombreCompleto"];
    return opcion;
}

dr1.add(createOption(), null);
dr2.add(createOption(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add it to the second element just clone it ..

```
dr2.add(opcion, null);
dr1.add(opcion.cloneNode(true), null);
```

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/7Kxdu/